# Triggering bootstrap tooltip by hovering over another element

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I am trying to trigger a bootstrap tooltip to appear on one element by hovering over another element.  I was thinking that I could maybe use JQuery to `addClass("hover")` to the element on which I want the tooltip displayed when I hover over the element that I wanted to do the trigger, but that doesn't seem to work because tooltip is not tied tied to the hoer pseudo class.

I made an example - in the example, I want the tooltip to appear on hover over the refresh button (that works) but also hover over the thumbs up button:

http://jsfiddle.net/cwzzq998/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where `#thumbs` is the added trigger, and `.resetPrice` is the element with the tooltip, add this code:

```
$('#thumbs').hover(
    function(e){$('.resetPrice').tooltip('toggle');}
);
```

See [This updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cwzzq998/2/)

HTH,

-Ted

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to avoid unexpected behavior with child elements

```
$('.parent-tooltip').hover(
      function(e){$(this).find('.child-tooltip').tooltip('show');},
      function(e){$(this).find('.child-tooltip').tooltip('hide');}
    );
```

HTML snippet example :

```
   <span class="parent-tooltip">the Play Store 
        <span class="child-tooltip" title="Google applications for Android">
        <i class="fa fa-google-play"></i></span>
    </span> and <span class="parent-tooltip">the App Store 
<span class="child-tooltip" title="applications Apple on IOS (iPhone)">
        <i class="fa fa-app-store-ios"></i></span>
    </span>
```